# Numpy - Find maximum point and value of data points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I just started to learn Numpy (and Scipy). I wrote a program to compute plot points for an f(x) function. (f(x) can't be given explicitly as I have to numerically solve an equation for each point.) I put the values in a 2D array:

```
[[x1,    x2,    x3,    ...],
 [f(x1), f(x2), f(x3), ...]]
```

My aim is now to find the maxima of the f(x) function, and get both it's location xm and it's value f(xm). Of course I could easily do this, but this seems to be something NumPy surely has a simple  function. The only thing I found is `numpy.amax`, but it only returns the maximum value at each axis. (e.g. numpy.amax([[1, 3, 2],[5, 7, 9]], axis=1) returns [3, 9].).

I have two questions:

1. Did I took the good approach on storing the data points, or is there a specific object in NumPy/SciPy to do this?
2. Is there a built-in NumPy/SciPy function to find the maxima of my dataset?

   This is the part of the code in question:

   ```
   def get_max(args):
       ti_0 = sp.pi / 2.0 + 1E-10
       ti_max = sp.pi - 1E-10
       iters = 10000

       step = (ti_max - ti_0) / iters
       ti = ti_0
       result = np.empty((2, iters), float_)   #the dataset, aim is to find the point where ret_energy is maximal
       for i in range(0, iters):
           tret = find_return_time(x, ti)
           ret_energy = ekin(tret, ti)
           ret_time = tret / sp.pi
           result[i, 0] = ret_time
           result[i, 1] = ret_energy
           ti += step

       emax = None
       #emax = find_maximal_return_energy(result) #-> ???
       return emax
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function:

```
data = np.array([[2, 4, 6, 8],[1, 3, 9, 7]])
x = data[0,:]
f = data[1,:]
i = np.argmax(f)
print x[i], f[i]
```

prints (6,9) as the (x, f(x)) pair with the largest value of f(x). Note that `argmax` returns only the first occurrence of the maximum value. If there is a possibility that the maximum value of `f` occurs multiple times and you want all values of `x`, then you could do

```
maxvalue = np.max(f)
print x[f == maxvalue], maxvalue
```

Comment: Out of interest: why is `data[1,:]` preferred over `data[1]`?

Comment: In this case it doesn't make a difference; it is just a habit of mine. I often have (x,y) data stored in the transpose format, and then I have to write `data[:,1]` to get the `y` values.

Answer (score 1):

1 - I think so

2 - argmax returns the index for the max value so you can retrieve that value and its corresponding x value.

```
idx = result[1].argmax()
xm = result[0,idx]
fxm = result[1,idx]
```